# Java socket simulates the problem of http requests

Tags: java, sockets

When I use java bio socket to simulate an http get request, I need to call socket.shutdownOutput(); socket.getInputStream().read() to read the correct data, otherwise it will keep blocking. This does not happen when I use SocketChannel to simulate http requests. Below is the test program I wrote.

```
public static void socket1(String host,int port,String path) throws Exception{
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port));
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    {
        out.write(("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write(("Host: " + host + ":" + port + "\r\n").getBytes());
        out.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        out.flush();
    }
     //This method needs to be called so that the following can correctly read the data returned by the server.
     // Otherwise, it will always be blocked in the in.read() method
     //socket.shutdownOutput();
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read()) != -1) {
        bos.write(len);
        System.out.println(len);
    }
    System.out.println("[" + new String(bos.toByteArray()) + "]");
    bos.close();
    in.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

When socket.shutdownOutput() is not called, the program will always be blocked on in.read(). When socket.shutdownOutput() is called, in.read() will return -1.

If I use SocketChannel simulation, the above situation will not happen, and the correct data can be obtained. The following is a code sample

```
public static void socket2(String host,int port,String path) throws Exception{
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
    channel.configureBlocking(false);
    channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port));
    while (true) {
        selector.select();
        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        for (Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selectedKeys.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            SelectionKey key = it.next();
            it.remove();
            if (key.isConnectable()) {
                SocketChannel client = ( SocketChannel)key.channel();
                if (client.isConnectionPending()) { 
                    client.finishConnect(); 
                    client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, ByteBuffer.allocate(1024));
                    {
                        client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").getBytes()));
                        client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("Host: " + host + ":" + port + "\r\n").getBytes()));
                        client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("\r\n".getBytes()));
                    }
                }
            } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
                buf.clear();
                int length = client.read(buf);
                buf.flip();
                while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
                    bos.write(buf.get());
                }
                System.out.println(buf);
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bos.toByteArray()));
                System.out.println("["+new String(bos.toByteArray())+"]");
                bos.close();
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 2);
                client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").getBytes()));
                client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("Host: " + host + ":" + port + "\r\n").getBytes()));
                client.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("\r\n".getBytes()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. InputStream.read returns -1 on end of stream
2. To end the socket OutputStream, you need to call shutdown

Quite simply, the stream isn't ended until you end it. That there is no more data right now is not the same as the stream being ended; you could always write more data until the stream is ended.